# How to validate using regex in Jquery? (without plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

After going through some answers on SO this is my code:

```
   $(".check").keyup(function () {
        var VAL = $(this).val();

      var email = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');

        if (email.test(VAL)) {
            alert('Great, you entered an E-Mail-address');
        }
    });

<input type="text" class="check"   />
<input type="text" class="check"   />
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: You probably need some regex tutorial...

Comment: This will fail to match a lot of valid email addresses, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: E-mail addresses usually contain lower-case characters.